# Spelling syntax colouring

Tags: miktex, windows, texworks, spelling

Is there a way to change the syntax colouring for spelling in TexWorks?

Currently red for comments and underlined red for mispelled words doesn't really stand out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underlined text is hard [coded by developers](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=6921) of TexWorks and cannot be changed.

As for the comments you can define your own rules for syntax highliting in a syntax-patterns.txt file in your TeXworks\configuration folder. After that you choose your syntax coloring from the top menu: Format -> Syntax Coloring.

This is an example of changing comments to blue. Add this to your syntax-patterns.txt file.

```
# comments
black/cyan;I            Y    %.*
```

[Here](http://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2011q3/004565.html) is a reference for more information.